# How to write array of bytes to a binary file in Java

Tags: java, binary, byte, datacontext, dataformat

How to write an array of bytes `b[i]` to a binary file in Java.

I need to write those bytes it into a "binary file" to be able to read it later using hex editor (AXE).

Some readers might be confused by "binary file", by binary file I don't mean a file filled by zeros and ones, I mean machine-readable form, something like this :
[binary files in text editor](https://www.nayuki.io/res/what-are-binary-and-text-files/binary-file-in-text-editor.png)

The hex editor suppose to read this data, [hex editor](https://www.sweetscape.com/articles/hex_editor.html)

From what I understand I need to byte stream that data into a file
Is there a command I could use for this purpose.

Any code would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), or a more modern alternative like [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). There are many ways to serialize / write binary information to files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the byte[] to a FileOutputStream pointing to the file:

```
private static void writeBytesToFile(byte[] b, String f) {

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)){
        out.write(b);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }          
}
```

Comment: Recommend updating using try-with-resources, greatly simplifies the code structuring. OP is likely using Java 7 or higher.

Comment: There you go. try-with-resources added.